# How do I get the data from API using Javascript and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

When I write something in the input and then press search I want to get the title from movies that has that word in it, how do I do that? Im using the omdb API. For example if I search for "Batman" I want to get all the movies titles that has "Batman" in it. Now when I search Batman I only get one Batman movie.

```js
document.getElementById("getForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadMovies(document.querySelector("input[name='query']").value);
  });
  
  function loadMovies(name) {
    var omdbAPI = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var omdbURL = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${name.replace(" ", "%20")}&type=movie&apikey=`;
    omdbAPI.open("get", omdbURL, true);
  
    omdbAPI.onload = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  
        console.log(result);
  
        var output = "";
          output +=
            '<div class="user">' +
            '<h3>Titel: ' + result.Title + '</h3>' +
            '<p>Year: ' + result.Year + '</p>' +
            '</div>';
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
      } else {
        alert("No results");
      }
    }
  
    omdbAPI.send();
  }
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" id="getForm">
  Movie: <input type="text" name="query">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div id="result">
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting any results because OMDB requires an API key and you aren't providing one. When sending a proper GET request you receive the following response: `{"Response":"False","Error":"No API key provided."}`.

You are also reloading the page by allowing the default form submission action to occur, instead use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the page reload from occurring when form submission occurs, then calling your function. I modified your function to include a name parameter to search with. The below should accomplish what you want, but since you don't have an API key you will still not get any results. Go [here](http://www.omdbapi.com/apikey.aspx), to get an API key.

```js
document.getElementById("getForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loadMovies(document.querySelector("input[name='query']").value);
});

function loadMovies(name) {
  var omdbAPI = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var omdbURL = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${name.replace(" ", "%20")}&type=movie`;
  omdbAPI.open("get", omdbURL, true);

  omdbAPI.onload = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.status == 200) {
      var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      console.log(result);

      var output = "";
      for (var i in result) {
        output +=
          '<div class="user">' +
          '<h3>Titel: ' + result.Title + '</h3>' +
          '</div>';
      }
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
    } else {
      alert("No results");
    }
  }

  omdbAPI.send();
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" id="getForm">
  Movie: <input type="text" name="query">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div id="result">

</div>
```